# cin.getline skips the reminder of the input if the user enters larger input than the char array

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I am trying to input data into an array of structure which contains a char array member and an int member as in here:

```
int main(){
    typedef struct {
        char name[10];
        int age;
    }Student;
    Student students[3];
    for (i=0;i<N;i++){
        cout<<"\n Enter name of student : "<< i+1<<" " ;
        cin.getline(students[i].name, 10);
        cout<<"\n Enter age of student : "<< i+1<<" ";
        cin>>students[i].age ;    
    }
```

But if I enter a name with more than 10 char (which the user might do), then the remainder of the input commands are ignored.

I tried adding `cin.ignore()` but it did not help.

I tried using `gets(students[i].name);` with `fflush(stdin);`, but that did not help either.

I cannot use `std::string`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just recalled the doc. of [`std::istream::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline):

> If the function extracts no characters (e.g. if count < 1), setstate(failbit) is executed.

That means after input of more than 10 characters (EOL included), the `std::cin` is in fail state. Hence, no more input can be extracted without reacting on this.

You may check this with [`std::istream::fail()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail).

To clear the fail state, [`std::istream::clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) can be used.

While preparing an MCVE, I realized another weakness:

Mixing `std::istream::getline()` with input stream operators `>>` needs special care because

- `getline()` reads until the end of line delimiter but
- `operator>>` reads whitespaces (incl. end of line) before the actual value.

Hence, `ignore()` should be used after error in `getline()` to discard the rest of line but `ignore()` should be used always after `std::cin >> students[i].age` to consume the end of line, at least.

So, I came up with this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const unsigned N = 3;
  const unsigned Len = 10;
  struct Student {
    char name[Len];
    int age;
  };
  Student students[N];
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Enter name of student " << i + 1 << ": ";
    std::cin.getline(students[i].name, Len);
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
      std::cerr << "Wrong input!\n";
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    std::cout <<"Enter age of student : " << i + 1 << " ";
    std::cin >> students[i].age;
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
      std::cerr << "Wrong input!\n";
      std::cin.clear();
    }
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
  // check read
  std::cout << "\nStudents:\n";
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    std::cout << i + 1 << ".: "
      << "name: '" << students[i].name << "'"
      << ", age: " << students[i].age << "\n";
  }
}
```

Input/Output:

```
Enter name of student 1: Johann Sebastian
Wrong input!
Enter age of student 1: 23
Enter name of student 2: Fred
Enter age of student 2: 22
Enter name of student 2: Fritz
Enter age of student 2: 19

Students:
1.: name: 'Johann Se', age: 23
2.: name: 'Fred', age: 22
3.: name: 'Fritz', age: 19
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8253b4e4fcc8f662)</kbd>